# macros in latex table

Tags: tables, macros, cell

I can't compile the file, and how can I insert macros in a table cell in LaTeX?

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
1&2\\
3&4\\
5& \nanName -(my macros)\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more code and also give a detailed error message. Unfortunately, "does not compile" is a bit broad ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a XY problem, but since guess X is impossible, this is the answer to Y:

> how can I insert macros in a table cell in LaTeX?

Just like you did. Put the macro inside a table cell. Ready.

> I can't compile the file.

You need at least: (1) make a complete document (2): include the `tabularx` package in the preamble to use the `tabularx` encvironemnt, and (3) include also a definition of that the hell is `\nanName`. In practice, assuming that the macro will to type "foo", this is :

Before of your code, insert some like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\nanName{foo}
\begin{document}
```

After your code, insert

```
\end{document}
```

Then, save the file with a name to remember, said `myfile.tex`

And finally, execute this from the command line:

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

The result should be a `myfile.pdf`, that opened with your PDF viewer, will show this table:

[image: mwe]

Comment: It works now! Thank You a lot!